# What is the fastest way to create image files

Tags: android, image, performance

I have a medical device that sends pixel's values in order to plot as an image (frame after frame).
I need to take the pixels and build from them an image on the screen. Currently with the code I wrote, I manage to receive 2fps for image size of 800x600.

What is the fastest way plot an image on screen? and doing it continuously.

```
 Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
 Canvas c = new Canvas(mBitmap);
 Paint paint = new Paint();
 int[] colorMatrix = new int[width * height];
 for (int i = 0; i < imageXY.length; i++) {
        int indexValue = Integer.parseInt(strValueIndex[i]);
        int pixelValue = Integer.parseInt(imageValue[indexValue - 1]);
        int pixelIndex = GetXY(imageXY[i]);
        //int pixelIndex = Integer.parseInt(imageXY[i].split(",")[2]);
        colorMatrix[pixelIndex] = pixelValue;
    }

    c.drawBitmap(colorMatrix, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height, false, paint);
    myImage.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
```

However its take about 500ms for each frame

Comment: Using Canvas, you're limited by the speeds of software rendering. You should try taking advantage of the graphics card for hardware acceleration, where you can stream pixel data to the GPU. This results in much faster rendering, but with added complexity if you're unfamiliar with OpenGL.

Comment: why does strValueIndex() and imageValue() and GetXY() all do?  Without source for those, it's hard to know what your loop is really doing. I suspect that the parsing of integers is a big factor.  Profiling your app will tell you exactly how it's spending its time

Comment: ... Also, you should try rendering and acquiring data in separate threads to decouple processing overhead in your render loop, if you aren't doing so already. This can be done via the Producer/Consumer pattern.

Comment: strValueIndex and imageValue are array's and GetXY() function doing very small calculation that should not impact the performence

Comment: I will use Producer/Consumer pattern for testing am using hard codded.

Comment: Alex, can you direct me where to start with openGL?

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest place to start OpenGL in Android: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html

I would also look into using multiple cores for this process; although the GPU based calculations may offer higher single core speeds, a fairly "simple" task such as this will be greatly accelerated by utilizing multiple cores and parallel processing, and shouldn't be too hard to implement. Here is an introduction to parallel processing on Android devices.

https://developer.qualcomm.com/blog/multi-threading-android-apps-multi-core-processors-part-1-2